# From where can I download the trace32 remote API

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm finding the documentation of LauterBach trace32 API for Remote Control and JTAG Access but can't be able to find the actual API.
Can someone please point to the location from where can I get the latest trac32 API for remote control and JTAG access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download it from 
http://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?scripts.html

This page contains lots of stuff, but since the links on this page change by date you have to do a text search for "API" on this page.

You should also find the files in your TRACE32 installation at `<T32SYS>/demo/api`. So on Windows this is usually `c:\T32\demo\api`